# tf,keras.sequential.pop() can't remove the last layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have written a very basic code to test the pop(9 methods. Even though both models use the same layers, they are independent of each other. Here is the code

```py
import tensorflow as tf

if (__name__== "__main__"):
    x= tf.ones((3, 3))
    x= tf.cast(x, tf.float32)

    ####################################################################
    layer1= tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation= "relu", name= "nlayer1")
    layer2= tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name= "nlayer2")
    layer3= tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, name= 'nlayer3')

    ####################################################################
    model_1= tf.keras.Sequential([layer1, layer2, layer3])
    y1= model_1(x)
    ####################################################################

    ####################################################################
    model_2= tf.keras.Sequential(name= 'model_2')
    model_2.add(layer1)
    model_2.add(layer2)
    model_2.add(layer3)
    y2= model_2(x)
    
    ####################################################################
    print('y1= ', y1)
    print('y2= ', y2)
    input('Press Enter to continue...')
    ####################################################################

    print('<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<The summary of model_5>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>')
    model_2.summary()
    print('*****************Removing the last layer of model_5******************')
    model_2.pop()
    model_2.summary()
```

What's wrong with trying to remove a layer of a model which doesn't depend on another model? The thrown error is like this:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(3, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='nlayer1_input'), name='nlayer1_input', description="created by layer 'nlayer1_input'") at layer "nlayer1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

Does anyone have any idea what may be wrong?

Kind Regards,

Problem with removing the last layer of a neural network using the pop() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't share your layer between models and hope to remove a layer successfully with `pop`. You have to copy your layers on your second model:

```
####################################################################
model_2= tf.keras.Sequential(name= 'model_2')
model_2.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense.from_config(layer1.get_config()))
model_2.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense.from_config(layer2.get_config()))
model_2.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense.from_config(layer3.get_config()))
y2= model_2(x)
```

Output after pop

```
>>> model_2.summary()
Model: "model_2"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 nlayer1 (Dense)             (3, 2)                    8         
                                                                 
 nlayer2 (Dense)             (3, 3)                    9         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 17
Trainable params: 17
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```